# using requirejs optimizer to minify to a single javascript and single css

Tags: javascript, css, requirejs, r.js

I am writing jQuery plugin and using requirejs in order to make my plugin modular and easier to code.
The plugin has also its own css files. Now, I want to combine and minify all the js files and css files. I am using r.js to so it. Here is the build.js configuration file that knows how to concatenate and minify js files into one file:

```
({
    baseUrl: 'js/plugin',
    optimize: 'none', // none, uglify or uglify2
    wrap: true,
    name: '../vendor/almond',
    include: 'main',
    out: '../dist/jquery.my-plugin.min.js'
})
```

How can I add an option to minify also css file? I saw the cssIn option, but where do I tells r.js wha is the output name? Do I need to use modules? If so, how?

Comment: maybe --- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/optimize-your-css-with-require-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r.js` automatically inlines contents of @import url(...) links in all `.css` files found in the project directory (thus concatenating multiple files into one master stylesheet).

In your current build configuration, however, with only `baseUrl` specified, `r.js` doesn't even know about the CSS folder (which is, presumably, somewhere in `../../style/` relative to `js/plugin/`).
You'd have to add the `appDir` and `dir` properties to your buildconfig file (both explained in detail in the [example config file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js)) and set project root (ie. `appDir`) to directory that contains both JS and CSS folders.

*Please note that, as mentioned in the documentation, adding `appDir` will require changing value of `baseUrl` to be relative to `appDir`.*